# New to programming, getting a run time error don't know why

Tags: java, runtime-error

Basically summarized in the title. https://ideone.com/E2BMS8 <-- that's a link to the code. I understand if you don't want to click it though so I'll paste it here as well. will just be disorganized. The code is supposed to flip the letters but keep words in the same position. I would like to figure that part out on my own though. Just need help with the run time error.

```
import java.util.*;

class Ideone {

  public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String sent, accum = "";
    char check, get;
    int len, count = 0;

    System.out.print("Please enter the sentance you want reversed: ");
    sent = input.nextLine();

    len = sent.length();

    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {

      check = sent.charAt(len - i);
      count += 1;

      if (check == ' ') {

        for (int p = 0; p < count; p++) {

          while (p < count) {

            get = sent.charAt(len - p);
            accum += (get + ' ');

          }
        }
      }


    }

    System.out.println("Reversed: " + accum);
  }
}
```

Comment: *Just need help with the run time error.* - maybe if you tell us what it is then we can help

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554734/what-causes-a-java-lang-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-and-how-do-i-prevent-it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error `String index out of range` is cause because of the len is one more than the index range. Remove one on the index such I did below:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Ideone {
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String sent, accum = "";
        char check, get;
        int len, count = 0;
        System.out.print("Please enter the sentance you want reversed: ");
        sent = input.nextLine();
        len = sent.length();
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            check = sent.charAt(len - i - 1);
            count += 1;
            if (check == ' ') {
                for (int p = 0; p < count; p++) {
                    get = sent.charAt(len - p - 1);
                    accum += (get + ' ');
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Reversed: " + accum);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a classical "off by one" error -- something you will run into a *lot* as you find your programming feet.  The issue in this case is the 0-based indexing.  That is, the first character of a string is at index 0, and the last is at index "*string length - 1*".  If we use `sent = "Test";` as an example, then:

```
sent.charAt(0) == 'T'
sent.charAt(1) == 'e'
sent.charAt(2) == 's'
sent.charAt(3) == 't'
sent.charAt(4) == ???  // "That's an error, Jim!"
```

Note that index 4 -- which perhaps confusingly is *also* the length of the string -- is out of bounds.  So, what happens during the first iteration of the loop, when `i == 0`:

```
check = sent.charAt(len - i);   // ERROR!  Because ...
==>   = sent.charAt((4) - (0));
==>   = sent.charAt( 4 );       // Doh!
```

I leave it to you to figure out how you might fix it.